# Live Video Stream Monitoring using IPAddress, Port and Crendentials

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, http-live-streaming

How to make application like monitoring live streaming of video in iOSs. I have done some R & D also but no luck. I have `IP Address`, `Port` and `Credentials`. But fail to get response.

If someone has experience with this kind of streaming, please help me with this.

I want to make application somewhat like this one. 
https://itunes.apple.com/kw/app/mobileeye+/id474667522?mt=8

I have done some R & D and find that this is possible using TCP/IP protocol, live streaming or RSTP protocol. Now a days i am finding and learning about this things. I will updates further as i will research.

Share me something(idea) if someone come across this kind of functionality.

Comment: "How do I make an application like X?" questions are probably overly broad. Do you have a more specific question and any work/research to show what's preventing you from doing what you want?

Comment: I have done some R & D also and find that this is possible using TCP/IP protocol, live streaming or RSTP protocol. Now a days i am finding and learning about this things. I will updates further as i will research.

Answer (score 0):

What type of camera is it? if it streams to a browser, you can play the stream in an HTML stream with `UIWebView loadHTMLString` and play it in there.

It would be something like this in a UIWebView:

```
NSString htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img alt=\"stream\" name=\"CameraVideo\" src=\"YOUR CAMERA URL"\>"]

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Audio is a whole different matter, depending on how your camera streams audio.

Comment: but url contains ipAddress, port and credential.

Comment: that is fine, as long as the URL is formatted correctly for the camera it will stream. For example `http://222.222.222.222:8080/videostream.cgi?usr=user&pwd=password`

Comment: will it use http or rtsp authentication for validation? provide me some tutorial if you have.

Comment: what kind of camera? you need to be more specific